# How to make camera follow player in Godot

Tags: godot

I'm making a top down game in Godot, when I add the Camera 2D node to my player and set it to current, the player is stuck in the same place and can no longer move. I get this error message

> *modules/gdscript/gdscript_tokenizer.cpp:1129 - Condition
>   "tk_rb[ofs].type != TK_IDENTIFIER" is true. Returned: StringName()*

Is there any way to fix this, or am I not providing enough information?

Comment: Just to confirm, the Camera2D is a child of the player, and the movement script is on the player node?

Comment: Its on kinematicbody2D, which is on the player node

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure about the error, but I remember when I was first starting, I had problems getting the player and camera to move together as well. It turned out that I had nothing in the background to show the movement, but in fact the camera and player were moving together perfectly - So perfectly, they seemed stationary until I added some un-moving sprites in the background. No chance this is the case here, is there?

Comment: I had a background, maybe i did something wrong with the background? it was a parallax background as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that the Camera 2D node is a child of the player and the camera has no scripts. just check the current check box in properties and it will work.

[image]